# Create master table for status column

Tags: sql, relational-database, rdbms

I have a table that represent a request sent through frontend

```
coupon_fetching_request
---------------------------------------------------------------
request_id    | request_time  | requested_by  | request_status
```

Above I tried to create a table to address the issue.
Here `request_status` is an `integer`. It could have some values as follows.

```
1 : request successful
2 : request failed due to incorrect input data
3 : request failed in otp verification
4 : request failed due to internal server error
```

That table is very simple and status is used to let frontend know what happened to sent request. I had discussion with my team and other developers were proposing that we should have a **status representation table**. At database side we are not gonna need this status. But team was saying that in future we may need to show simple output from database to show what is the status of all request. According to [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) principle I don't think it is a good idea.

Currently I have coded to convert returned `request_status` value to descriptive value at frontend. I tried to convince team that I can creat an enumuration at business layer to represent meaning of the status OR I could add documentation at frontend and in java but failed to convince them.

The table proposed is as follows

```
coupon_fetching_request_status
---------------------------------------------------
status_id   | status_code   | status_description
```

My question is, Is it necessary to create table for such a simple status in similar cases.

*I tried to create simple example to address the problem. In real time the table is to represent a **Discount Coupon Code Request** and status representing if the code is successfully fetched*

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your use case.

To start with: in you main table, you are already storing `request_status` as an integer, which is a good thing (if you were storing the whole description, like `'request successful'`, that would not be optimized).

The main question is: will you eventually need to display that data in a human-readable format?

If no, then it is probably useless to create a representation table.

If yes, then having a representation table would be a good thing, instead of adding some code in the presentation layer to do the transcodification; let the data live in the database, and the frontend take care of presentation only.

Since this table can be easily created when needed, a pragmatic approach would be to hold on until you have a real need for the representation table.

Comment: Edited to add little more details in Question. I mentioned that according to YAGNI we should just not think about future. There is not even any best practice to do it like this.

Comment: @afzalex: ah ok, you did not originally mentionned that you needed to present the data. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I want to mention that If I create a representation table then I will have to fetch status description value from db to return to frontend while registering request. Isn't it extra unnecessary overhead?

Comment: One more thing. Suppose I take this approach as correct. Then suppose I have another status with big description value or say description value for all status code is big. Now think If I have to list all the requests from this table at frontend. Now do you still think sending description from database is good? I am seeing this as strange. instead I could send just code (if not number) to represent status.

Comment: @afzalex: once the status description is stored in another table, you would typically use a JOIN to return it when querying the main table. With a properly defined foreign key relation, the overhead involved by the additional JOIN (and for fetching a few more bytes per record) will be very tiny, since the description table will have very few records, hence the performance hit would not be noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

You should create the reference table in the database.  You currently have business logic on the application side, interpreting data stored in the database.  This seems dangerous.

What does "dangerous" mean?  It means that ad-hoc queries on the database might need to re-implement the logic.  That is prone to error.

It means that if you add a reporting front end, then the reports have to re-implement the logic.  That is prone to error and a maintenance nightmare.

It means that if you have another developer come along, or another module implemented, then the logic might need to be re-implemented.  Red flag.

The simplest solution is to have a reference table to define the official meanings of the codes.  The application should use this table (via `join`) to return the strings.  The application should not be defining the meaning of codes stored in the database.  YAGNI doesn't apply, because the application is so in need of this information that it implements the logic itself.

Comment: To this answer I have some queries. Please read my [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58209019/create-master-table-for-status-column/58209710#comment102796632_58209082)